# How to get jQuery scrollTo plugin to behave within Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, scrollto

I can't seem to get the scrollTo jQuery plugin to work within my Facebook app. I'm using it to move the window, as I have a form that needs to grow vertically as it is filled out. My code works fine normally, but not in the Facebook environment.

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and if there are generally any special considerations that need to be taken when attempting to move the browser "window" within an iframe?

If there is an alternate solution to the problem that bypasses the use of scrollTo, I'm open to that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to integrate your plugin with [FB.Canvas.setSize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.canvas.setsize/)

Comment: Hm, I'm already using this method to change the size of the canvas, but I'd like to move the window to a specific point down the page. Currently, I'm using scrollTo, which works when I'm not in Facebook, of course

Comment: Have you enabled the option to use the parameter manually in app configuration?